# Listview no cambia al añadir elementos

Tags: c#, xamarin, listview, xaml

Con un formulario estoy creando una lista, pero al añadir un elemento no es visible en la vista.
De hecho, el elemento añadido es el resaltado en naranja, y si añado más elementos se añaden y son "seleccionables", pero no lee lo que hay en el Label del XAML.

[image: ListView]

El botón Añadir Material ejecuta la siguiente función:

```
 public void AddMaterial()
    {
        var materialYUnidades = new MaterialYUnidades
        {
            Material = SelectedMaterial,
            Unidades = UnidadesMaterial,
        };
        ListaMateriales.Add(materialYUnidades);
    }
```

La lista:

```
public ObservableCollection<MaterialYUnidades> ListaMateriales { get; set; }
```

No creo que sea error de la vista, pero añado el código por si acaso:

```
<ListView
   x:Name="ListaMateriales"
   ItemsSource="{Binding ListaMateriales}">
   <ListView.ItemTemplate>
       <DataTemplate>
           <ViewCell>
               <Grid Margin="10">
                   <Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="*" />
                       <ColumnDefinition Width="Auto" />
                   </Grid.ColumnDefinitions>
                   <Label Text="{Binding Material.Descripcion}" 
                      TextColor="Black" 
                      Grid.Column="0" />
                   <Label Text="{Binding Unidades}" 
                      TextColor="Black" 
                      Grid.Column="1" />
               </Grid>
           </ViewCell>
       </DataTemplate>
    </ListView.ItemTemplate>
</ListView>
```

Gracias de antemano.

Comment: Has probado a actualizar la vista una vez que añades un item?

Comment: @PabloSimonDiEstefano si, y nada, siguen sin aparecer

Comment: no entiendo como tienes tu binding a "listaMateriales" y el nombre del controlador es "listaMaeriales", estas utilizando un binding source? en ese caso, estas seguro que estas actualizando el "listaMateriales" correcto y no una instancia diferente?

Comment: @Mike está dentro de un ViewModel y en el XAML está el BindingContext a ese VM, eso funciona bien puesto que ya he hecho más vistas y todo ha ido bien.
El caso es que si que detecta cuando añado objetos a la ListView, pero no muestra nada de ellos, pero si estoy usando el "listaMateriales" correcto

Comment: hmmm, son "Material" y "Unidades"  propiedades con get;set; ?

Comment: @Mike no sé por qué al crear el model lo dejé así: public Material Material;
Al añadir el get y set todo ha funcionado bien, ni me habia dado cuenta, muchísimas gracias!

Comment: Igual es una tontería, pero añade elementos manualmente al inicializar la lista solo para comprobar que espacio ocupa el control ListView.

Answer (score -1):

Espero que estés bien, esto sucede es debido a que como estas trabajando con *Bindings* al momento de hacer modificaciones en tu `viewmodel` las *Views* no detectan esos cambios y por eso no te muestra cuando tu agregas items en tu `ObservsbleCollection`.

Para solucionar eso debes implementar en tu `viewmodel` un `NotifyPropertyChanged`, en el cual su función es notificar a tus *Views* que has actualizado la información y que te muestre el refresco de la misma, entonces para implementar esto aquí te dejo el siguiente video:

https://youtu.be/zhp6Le2WByY